# How to return values in a JSON object in Polymer?

Tags: json, polymer

New-ish to JSON. The following Polymer code works (the string is returned) for when the JSON file is a basic array (see target1.json), but when the data is within an object (target2.json), I'm not sure how to return the values inside of it?

```
<dom-module id="x-app">
    <template>

      <iron-ajax 
        url="target1.json" 
        handle-as="json"
        last-response="{{data}}"
        auto
      ></iron-ajax>

      <iron-list 
      id="itemsList" 
      items="[[data]]" 
      >

            <template>
                    <div class="pad"> 
                        [[item.name]]
                    </div>
            </template>

     </iron-list>

     </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-app',
          properties: {
            selectedItems: {
              type: Object
            }
          },
        });
  });
</script>
```

target1.json:

```
 [
    {
        "name": "blah blah blah"
    },
    {
        "name": "blah blah blah 2"
    },
]
```

target2.json:

```
{
    "listing": [
        {
            "name": "blah blah blah"
        },
        {
            "name": "blah blah blah 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<iron-ajax>` is returning an object with an array inside (`listing`) but your `<iron-list>` is expecting an array.

So instead of

```
<iron-list id="itemsList" items="[[data]]">...</iron-list>
```

you should instead refer to the `listing` array inside `data`

```
<iron-list id="itemsList" items="[[data.listing]]">...</iron-list>
```